# C++ -- Method for Casting between different Templated versions of a class

Tags: c++, templates, downcast

So, I have a single templated class, `B`, which inherits from a non-template class `A`. Now, this templated version `B`, has a set of four valid and known template classes, call them `B<uint8_t>, B<uint16_t>, B<uint32_t>, B<uint64_t>`.

Currently, I am storing these in a map, `boost::unordered_map<std::string, A>`, and I would like to create some way to cast to the different types. I can easily differentiate based on a `A::width()` method which returns 8, 16, 32, or 64 respectively.

I have been racking my brain for a good design but I can't figure out a way to get a better solution than having every use casting themselves.

Here is a minimum working case:

```
class A {
  std::size_t width() const = 0;
};

template <typename value> class B : public A {
  std::size_t width() const {
    return sizeof(value) * 8;
  }
};
```

Within usage:

```
boost::unordered_map<std::string, A *> _bmap;

template <class T> T cast_A(A * const a) {
    switch (a->width()) {
    case 8: return dynamic_cast<B<uint8_t> *>(a);
    // removed for brevity
}
```

The problem with this is that it forces the user to check the runtime type of the `A` class after, aka making the cast method absolutely useless.

I welcome any input. :)

Comment: The design doesn't really make much sense as stated. What exactly are you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: you didn't explain details about `A` and `B`, so I recommend to look to the `boost::variant` -- possible you may find another way to solve your task

Comment: If your users know beforehand what type they need, why are you lumping them all in a single container?

Comment: If you are concerned with the how often the usage of these types require checking the result of a cast you are casting too much. If you are casting too much there is IMHO a problem with your design. Unfortunately you did not provide enough information about what you are trying to accomplish to address that aspect of your goals. I suggest you revisit your design and see if you can expand the contract of the base class to reduce or eliminate the need to cast.

Comment: Originally, this was a better design due to the contract being that there wasn't any dynamic nature to it. There was one of each made, etc.. The design requirements have changed and I think I might need to stop trying to reuse the old versions, and aim for new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use, e.g., a templated `get()` method which converts to the asked for size via a `virtual` method going through the largest supported type. If the conversion would loose bits (checked at run-time) you could produce an error.

Answer (score 0):

I think the downcasting is not very good idea in this case. It seems to be a design problem.

However, you could try to implement something like [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) for these classes. It may solve your problem, but I'm not sure, because there are no use examples of B objects.